# ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> webservice's parameter

Tags: java, web-services, arraylist, hashmap

I have a web service that should accept as parameter a `java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<String>>` but the web service method only accepts an array, for example, `my.other.ArrayList[]`.

How can I pass to it what I want?

Then it returns a `my.other.HashMap` but I want to change this Map in my `java.util.HashMap<String, MyClass>`, also for this, how can I do?

Thank you very much.

wsmethod as client.

```
public my.other.HashMap getWhatIWant(my.other.ArrayList[] arg0) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
```

true paramethers

```
public java.util.HashMap<String, MyClass> getWhatIWant(java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<String>> arg0) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `my.other` with `java.util`?

Comment: The webservice accepts a standard java array (`[]`) whose elements are `ArrayList`s, right?

Comment: @cheeken what do you mean when you are saying replacing? I only tried to pass from my java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<String> to an Object[] that has for elements Object[] (I tried also with String[]), then I did the cast when I pass my Object[] parameter to the service method but didn't work.

Comment: @vulkanino Yes. I edited the first post, I think you can understand better what is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your `java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<String>>` in an array you can use for example :

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>res=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    my.other.ArrayList<String> [] array = res.toArray(new my.other.ArrayList[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you alain but it gives me an error: The type my.other.ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: Ok, you've tried with `my.other.ArrayList [] array = res.toArray(new my.other.ArrayList[0]);` ?

Comment: of course I did, thank you but I "solved" the problem: I modified the ws method, it was the best and easiest choice. Thank you anyway